# How to fix dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format error?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I have the following error on a code sample:

```
raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Fall Semester 2018 Printed: Caux, 15/01/2021
```

Following is the code sample:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

text = 'Fall Semester 2018 Printed: Caux, 15/01/2021'
date_value = dparser.parse(text)
print(date_value)
```

Comment: parser take date type format in a string form and then convert it. extract date and feed it to parser

Comment: I found the issue, just because there are two date types and `'2018'` and `'15/01/2021'`, the dparser is failing to select one out of them @Mehmaam

Answer (score 1):

`dateutil.parser` was not able to parse the string `'Fall Semester 2018 Printed: Caux, 15/01/2021'` as a date.

You need to pass a string to it which it is able to parse.

Try splitting the string at the comma and passing only `'15/01/2021'`.

Alternatively, try setting the `fuzzy` or `fuzzy_with_tokens` parameters to `True`. This makes the parser more tolerant regarding the input format.

Comment: okay, but if I have to pass '15/01/2021' specifically by splitting, than what is the use of dateutil.parser?

Comment: To convert the string `'15/01/2021'` to a `datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 15)`.